# using fetch with ES2015 modules in Canary

Tags: module, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I'm trying out ES2015 modules in Chrome Canary Version 60.0.3102.0. My script.js file reads like this:

```
import {fetchJSON} from './functions/fetchJSON.js';

const configFile = 'config.json';

const init = () => {
  fetchJSON(configFile)
    .then((data) => {        // code fails here at ln.7
      console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
};

init();
```

and my fetchJSON.js file reads like this:

```
export function fetchJSON(url) {
  const fetchJSON = fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);      // data exists and is reported in the console
      return data;
    });
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
script.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at init (script.js:7)
    at script.js:14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fetchJSON function isn't returning anything. Because of that, when you try chaining a .then on the result of fetchJSON, you're getting the Uncaught TypeError - undefined.

Solution: return your Promise chain in your fetchJSON function:

```
export function fetchJSON(url) {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      return data;
    });
}
```

Comment: So I actually don't need:
 `.then(data => { return data; });`